# Map value from 1st key value pair to all values in 2nd key value pair in a python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a requirement to fetch dictionary items which contain lists. Suppose there are 2 key values pairs in my dictionary, I need to query each value from a 1st key value pair and map all the values from the 2nd key value pair & store it in a file. I am new to Python and have seen few online forums but nothing matched my requirement. Any help is greatly appreciated.

E.g.

My dictionary looks like this:

```
test_dict = {'Host': ['H1','H2'], 'IP':['IP1','IP2','IP3','IP4','IP5']}
```

My file should look like this which I will take it as input to my other program:

```
H1 IP1

H1 IP2

H1 IP3

H1 IP4

H1 IP5

H2 IP1

H2 IP2

H2 IP3

H2 IP4

H2 IP5
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5):

Use product form itertools to get all the pairs. And then write it into a file:

```
In [24]: from itertools import product

In [25]: test_dict = {'Host': ['H1','H2'], 'IP':['IP1','IP2','IP3','IP4','IP5']}

In [26]: with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    ...:     for i in product(test_dict['Host'], test_dict['IP']):
    ...:         f.write('{} {}\n'.format(*i))

In [27]: cat test.txt
H1 IP1
H1 IP2
H1 IP3
H1 IP4
H1 IP5
H2 IP1
H2 IP2
H2 IP3
H2 IP4
H2 IP5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `product` from `itertools` to do that:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> test_dict = {'Host': ['H1','H2'], 'IP':['IP1','IP2','IP3','IP4','IP5']}
>>> with open('file.txt', 'a') as f: # To Write The Output into a text file
...     print(*map(' '.join, product(test_dict['Host'], test_dict['IP'])), sep='\n', file=f)
...  
>>> with open('file.txt') as f: # To Read The File and Check The Result
...    print(f.read())
...
H1 IP1
H1 IP2
H1 IP3
H1 IP4
H1 IP5
H2 IP1
H2 IP2
H2 IP3
H2 IP4
H2 IP5
```

Comment: Thanks very much Mhd. This is really helpful

Comment: Anytime dear :)